# how to give user input to build.xml using ANT

Tags: java, ant, build.xml, antbuilder

I have several properties file in my resources folder. Based on user input, I need to build a JAR with Apache ANT and place it and the corresponding property file separately in the output folder.

I am very new to ANT and have no idea on how to define the build.xml. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` task will allow you to prompt for user input, either free form or multiple choice, and create a property containing the user's input.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Examples of using the `<input>` task are in the [Ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html).